# Looking to optimize multiple similar SVG elements with similar linear gradient

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a menu system I am implementing that will have animations for each element. I have exported the SVG code from Illustrator, and I see that there are some potential areas for optimization.

There are two layers, the colored stars and white stars that are behind the colored stars.

Each star in the menu is the same, just in different positions, the top layer with different colors. There are also two "arches" that are the EXACT same, just positioned differently.

[Menu top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjar4.png)

The SVG code looks like this:

```
<g id="white_stars">
            <g id="star_3">

                <radialGradient id="SVGID_3_" cx="37138.957" cy="-8340.4863" r="53.5295" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.2812 0 0 -0.2812 10595.4463 -2308.418)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.12" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.7"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.24" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.49"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.35" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.34"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.46" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.21"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.58" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.12"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.7" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.05"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.84" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.01"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
                </radialGradient>
                <circle fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" cx="151.421" cy="37.544" r="15.093"/>
                <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="151.421" cy="37.544" r="3.094"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26139.7969" y1="-8190.5161" x2="26139.7969" y2="-8153.4463" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.4687 0 0 -0.4687 12403.4668 -3792.7949)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.18" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.73"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.29" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.79" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.82" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.85"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.86" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.94" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.39"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.98" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.32"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" enable-background="new    " d="M150.53,45.372V29.717
        c0-0.469,0.375-0.844,0.844-0.844l0,0c0.469,0,0.844,0.375,0.844,0.844v15.655c0,0.469-0.375,0.844-0.844,0.844l0,0
        C150.952,46.215,150.577,45.84,150.53,45.372z"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26125" y1="-8172.0156" x2="26154.3984" y2="-8172.0156" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.4687 0 0 -0.4687 12403.4668 -3792.7949)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.18" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.73"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.29" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.79" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.82" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.85"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.86" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.94" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.39"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.98" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.32"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#SVGID_5_)" enable-background="new    " d="M144.531,37.544L144.531,37.544
        c0,0.515,0.422,0.937,0.938,0.937h11.906c0.515,0,0.937-0.422,0.937-0.937l0,0c0-0.516-0.422-0.938-0.937-0.938h-11.906
        C144.953,36.607,144.531,37.029,144.531,37.544z"/>
            </g>
            <g id="star_4">

                <radialGradient id="SVGID_6_" cx="620.1162" cy="-244.0107" r="28.499" gradientTransform="matrix(0.4687 0 0 0.4687 -81.451 159.046)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.12" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.7"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.14" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.24" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.49"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.35" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.34"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.46" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.21"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.58" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.12"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.7" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.05"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.84" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.01"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
                </radialGradient>
                <circle fill="url(#SVGID_6_)" cx="209.447" cy="46.075" r="15.093"/>
                <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="209.447" cy="46.075" r="3.094"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_7_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26015.8984" y1="-8208.7705" x2="26015.8984" y2="-8171.7026" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.4687 0 0 -0.4687 12403.4668 -3792.7949)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.18" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.73"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.29" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.79" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.82" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.85"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.86" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.94" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.39"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.98" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.32"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#SVGID_7_)" enable-background="new    " d="M208.604,53.902V38.247
        c0-0.469,0.374-0.843,0.843-0.843l0,0c0.469,0,0.844,0.375,0.844,0.843v15.655c0,0.469-0.375,0.844-0.844,0.844l0,0
        C208.979,54.746,208.604,54.371,208.604,53.902z"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_8_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26001.1992" y1="-8190.2148" x2="26030.6348" y2="-8190.2148" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.4687 0 0 -0.4687 12403.4668 -3792.7949)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.18" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.73"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.29" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.79" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.82" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.85"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.86" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.94" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.39"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.98" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.32"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#SVGID_8_)" enable-background="new    " d="M202.558,46.075L202.558,46.075
        c0,0.516,0.422,0.938,0.938,0.938H215.4c0.516,0,0.938-0.422,0.938-0.938l0,0c0-0.516-0.422-0.938-0.938-0.938h-11.905
        C202.979,45.137,202.558,45.559,202.558,46.075z"/>
            </g>
            <g id="star_2">

                <radialGradient id="SVGID_9_" cx="372.6289" cy="-242.5107" r="29.999" gradientTransform="matrix(0.4687 0 0 0.4687 -81.451 159.046)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.12" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.7"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.14" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.24" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.49"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.35" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.34"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.46" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.21"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.58" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.12"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.7" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.05"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.84" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.01"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
                </radialGradient>
                <circle fill="url(#SVGID_9_)" cx="93.394" cy="46.075" r="15.093"/>
                <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="93.394" cy="46.075" r="3.094"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_10_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26263.5977" y1="-8208.7705" x2="26263.5977" y2="-8171.7026" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.4687 0 0 -0.4687 12403.4668 -3792.7949)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.18" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.73"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.29" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.79" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.82" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.85"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.86" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.94" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.39"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.98" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.32"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#SVGID_10_)" enable-background="new    " d="M92.503,53.902V38.247
        c0-0.469,0.375-0.843,0.844-0.843l0,0c0.469,0,0.844,0.375,0.844,0.843v15.655c0,0.469-0.375,0.844-0.844,0.844l0,0
        C92.925,54.746,92.503,54.371,92.503,53.902z"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_11_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26248.8008" y1="-8190.2148" x2="26278.2363" y2="-8190.2148" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.4687 0 0 -0.4687 12403.4668 -3792.7949)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.18" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.73"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.29" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.79" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.82" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.85"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.86" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.94" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.39"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.98" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.32"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#SVGID_11_)" enable-background="new    " d="M86.504,46.075L86.504,46.075
        c0,0.516,0.422,0.938,0.938,0.938h11.905c0.516,0,0.938-0.422,0.938-0.938l0,0c0-0.516-0.422-0.938-0.938-0.938H87.441
        C86.879,45.137,86.504,45.559,86.504,46.075z"/>
            </g>
            <g id="white_star_1">

                <radialGradient id="SVGID_12_" cx="254.1348" cy="-194.5132" r="31.4989" gradientTransform="matrix(0.4687 0 0 0.4687 -81.451 159.046)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.12" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.7"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.14" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.24" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.49"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.35" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.34"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.46" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.21"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.58" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.12"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.7" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.05"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.84" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.01"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
                </radialGradient>
                <circle fill="url(#SVGID_12_)" cx="38.086" cy="68.573" r="15.093"/>
                <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="38.086" cy="68.573" r="3.093"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_13_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26381.5977" y1="-8256.7705" x2="26381.5977" y2="-8219.7031" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.4687 0 0 -0.4687 12403.4668 -3792.7949)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.18" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.73"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.29" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.79" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.82" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.85"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.86" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.94" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.39"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.98" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.32"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#SVGID_13_)" enable-background="new    " d="M37.195,76.4V60.746c0-0.469,0.375-0.844,0.844-0.844
        l0,0c0.469,0,0.844,0.375,0.844,0.844V76.4c0,0.469-0.375,0.844-0.844,0.844l0,0C37.617,77.244,37.195,76.869,37.195,76.4z"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_14_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26366.8008" y1="-8238.2158" x2="26396.2402" y2="-8238.2158" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.4687 0 0 -0.4687 12403.4668 -3792.7949)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.18" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.73"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.29" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.79" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.82" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.85"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.86" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.94" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.39"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.98" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.32"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#SVGID_14_)" enable-background="new    " d="M31.196,68.573L31.196,68.573
        c0,0.516,0.422,0.938,0.938,0.938h11.905c0.516,0,0.938-0.422,0.938-0.938l0,0c0-0.516-0.422-0.938-0.938-0.938H32.133
        C31.571,67.636,31.196,68.058,31.196,68.573z"/>
            </g>
            <g id="star_5">

                <radialGradient id="SVGID_15_" cx="737.1104" cy="-194.5132" r="29.9989" gradientTransform="matrix(0.4687 0 0 0.4687 -81.451 159.046)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.12" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.7"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.14" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.24" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.49"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.35" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.34"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.46" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.21"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.58" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.12"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.7" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.05"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.84" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.01"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
                </radialGradient>
                <circle fill="url(#SVGID_15_)" cx="264.756" cy="68.573" r="15.093"/>
                <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="264.756" cy="68.573" r="3.093"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_16_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="25897.8984" y1="-8256.7705" x2="25897.8984" y2="-8219.7031" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.4687 0 0 -0.4687 12403.4668 -3792.7949)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.18" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.73"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.29" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.79" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.82" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.85"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.86" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.94" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.39"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.98" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.32"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#SVGID_16_)" enable-background="new    " d="M263.912,76.4V60.746
        c0-0.469,0.375-0.844,0.844-0.844l0,0c0.469,0,0.844,0.375,0.844,0.844V76.4c0,0.469-0.375,0.844-0.844,0.844l0,0
        C264.287,77.244,263.912,76.869,263.912,76.4z"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_17_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="25883.1992" y1="-8238.2158" x2="25912.6348" y2="-8238.2158" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.4687 0 0 -0.4687 12403.4668 -3792.7949)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.18" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.73"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.29" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.79" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.82" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.85"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.86" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.66"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.94" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.39"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.98" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.32"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#SVGID_17_)" enable-background="new    " d="M257.866,68.573L257.866,68.573
        c0,0.516,0.422,0.938,0.938,0.938h11.905c0.516,0,0.938-0.422,0.938-0.938l0,0c0-0.516-0.422-0.938-0.938-0.938h-11.905
        C258.288,67.636,257.866,68.058,257.866,68.573z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
```

The stop offsets are the same within each radial and linear gradient elements, but when I add them as defs and reference them by url#, the positioning is off. I have tried:

```
<defs>
                <linearGradient id="linearGradientOne" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-7694.9893" y1="8409.7441" x2="-7694.9893" y2="7886.7349" gradientTransform="matrix(0.4687 0 0 0.4687 3758.0625 -3681.2319)">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.4"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.38"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.06" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.27"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.11" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.17"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.17" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.09"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.24" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.04"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.33" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.01"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.76" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.01"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.85" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.03"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.92" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.08"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.97" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.15"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.2"/>
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
<path opacity="0.46" fill="url(#linearGradientOne)" enable-background="new" d="M150.53,45.372V29.717
        c0-0.469,0.375-0.844,0.844-0.844l0,0c0.469,0,0.844,0.375,0.844,0.844v15.655c0,0.469-0.375,0.844-0.844,0.844l0,0
        C150.952,46.215,150.577,45.84,150.53,45.372z"/>
```

But the positioning is something I am not quite grasping. I have searched Google and Stack Overflow and found similar questions, but none that help me understand how to reduce the code and optimize the SVG.

Thanks!

Comment: The positioning is x1, y1, x2, y2. It seems that's different in your different cases. It's possible converting to objectBoundingBox coordinates might fix this depending on what you're trying to do here.

Comment: can you put together a fiddle?

Comment: As Robert says, you probably want to convert your gradients to use `gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"`. You can read about that here
: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#pservers-LinearGradientElementGradientUnitsAttribute